# How do I use WS-* Standards with Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, soap, ws-security, ws-addressing

Web Service requirements are specified in documents.

- WS-Security 1.1
- WS-Trust 1.3
- WS-SecurityPolicy 1.2

Can I use Delphi 2010 and this web service or 
Can I create a dll with any other **native language**?

See:
http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/wss/charter.php
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **Apache Axis2/C**, an open source project, released under the Apache 2.0 License.

> Apache Axis2/C is a Web services engine implemented in the C
>   programming language.

It is based on the extensible and flexible Axis2 architecture (for the Java platform).

> The following WS-* specifications are supported, either as built in
>   modules or as separate Apache projects:
>
> - WS-Addressing - Built in to Axis2/C
> - WS-Policy - Built in to Axis2/C
> - WS-Security - Implemented by Apache Rampart/C project
> - WS-SecurityPolicy - Built in to Axis2/C
> - WS-ReliableMessaging - Implemented by Apache Sandesha2/C project
> - WS-Eventing - Implemented by Apache Savan/C project

I have not studied it in detail, but in my experience most Apache projects are among the best open source projects, well documented and widely used in (non-commercial and commercial) applications.

Update: Support for WS-Trust is mentioned on the Apache Rampart/C pages.

Comment: Other native options are WWSAPI and WS02 (https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=392627&tstart=0)